# Split string and separate value & unit

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check if a string has the format: `1234g`, `1234 g`, `1.234kg` or `1.234 kg`
That means there is a number value and after that the unit "g" or "kg" with or without space between them.

Don't know how to add the unit in the regEx:

```
string.match(/^[0-9]+$/)
```

After the check I need to split the string to get just the numeric value. How do I do that?

Comment: BTW: Use Regexp's `test` method instead of String's `match` if you only want to test a string for some Regexp pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var match = string.match(/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s?k?g$/);
var numericValue = match ? match[1] : null;
```

Here is the [demo for the regex](http://regex101.com/r/xD9vJ1/4)

Comment: Need to account for the decimal `.` as well

Comment: I missed that. Updated the answer.

Comment: `[\d.]+` looks pretty lazy to me (`...1...`?). `\d+(\.\d+)?` would be more accurate.

Comment: Is it possible to add a function to change , to .? 1,234 should become 1.234 before checking via regEx...

Comment: Yes, you can use `var match = string.replace(',', '.').match(...)`

Comment: Thanks! Ok, last one: If the user makes the input without a unit, it should lead to the output of the value. i.e.: `1.2` --> `numericValue = 1.2`

Answer (score 2):

#### Here's one way of splitting values and units:

```js
[
 "1s",
 " 0.3 ms  ",
 "  $ 20",
 "10  kg "
]
.forEach(test => {
  var unit  = test.trim().split(/\d+/g).filter(n=>n).pop().trim(),
      value = test.trim().split(unit).filter(n=>n)[0].trim()
  console.log({value, unit})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if you wanted to use replace instead of regex.

All you need from the example is function removeKg():

```
<html>
<head>
    <style><!-- Your Styles --></style>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">

        var a = ['1234g', '1234 g', '1.234kg', '1.234 kg'];

        $(document).ready(function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                $('#output').append('<p>' + removeKg(a[i]) + '</p>');
            }
        });

        function removeKg(x) {
            return x.replace('k','').replace('g','').replace(' ','');
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output">
        <!-- Results here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Produces the following:

```
1234

1234

1.234

1.234
```